# Asp.net forms authentication on different port?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, port, windows-authentication

We have an asp.net intranet application that uses Windows authentication over 80/443.  We now need to add support for forms authentication over SSL on a different port for users on a different network.

My initial thought was to add a login form to the site, then run the site twice on each server, one configured to use Windows authentication on 80/443, and one configured to use forms authentication on the new port.  This is because of some bad experiences with mixed-mode authentication hacks back in the day.

However, I'd rather not pay the CPU and RAM cost of running two instances of the site on each server if I don't have to.  Is there a cleaner way to to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why couldn't you run it as 2 sites on 1 server? The first site bound to ports 80/443 and using Windows authentication; the second site bound to the new port, and using Forms authentication. The two sites would be copies of each other, differing only by the web.config.

Comment: I'd rather not have two sites competing for CPU and RAM on the same server if possible. :)

Comment: OK. Note that the allocation of a second site isn't a big resource drain. The resources needed to accommodate 1000 hits to a single site isn't much different than the resources needed to accommodate 500 hits (each) to two sites.

Comment: This would be a new set of users, so their load would be in addition to the existing load.  Anyway, it sounds like you agree with my default direction.

Comment: Okay, looks like the 2-instance approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[Internet Security and Acceleration (ISA) Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/forefront/bb758895) can handle this kind of setup.